# How to define exceptions to rubocop rules?

Tags: rubocop

We are using this setting to require space before code blocks

```
Layout/SpaceBeforeBlockBraces:
  EnforcedStyle: space
```

However, in RSpec examples, we do not use the space after `expect` and `change` methods when they use blocks for readability:

```
expect{ calling_the_method }.to change{ Model.all.size }.by(1)
```

Rubocop complains about the code above.
Is it possible to tell it to ignore blocks after specific methods or ignore lines matching regex?

I have tried:

```
Layout/SpaceBeforeBlockBraces:
  EnforcedStyle: space
  IgnoredPatterns: ['\A\s*((?:expect)|(.*change))']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to tell it [the SpaceBeforeBlockBraces cop] to ignore blocks after specific methods or ignore lines matching regex?

No. As of 2018-08-12, I don't think that `SpaceBeforeBlockBraces` supports the `IgnoredPattern` option, but it might be an easy PR. The `IgnoredPattern` option is a mixin (`rubocop/cop/mixin/ignored_pattern.rb`) so you could just `include` it into whatever cop you want. Rubocop has strict rules for contributions, so if you do a PR, make sure to read all instructions thoroughly.

The `SpaceBeforeBlockBraces` cop should support the `Exclude` option, if you want to exclude your test directory. I think all cops support `Include` and `Exclude`.